# Best way to test if large file exists

Tags: python, pandas, exception, operating-system, large-files

I would like to know what is most efficient way to test if a large file exists locally (without loading it in memory). If it doesn't exists (or not readable) then download it. The goal is to upload the data in a pandas DataFrame.

I wrote the snippet below which is working (and tested with a small file). What about correctness and pythonic programming?

```
url = "http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv" # 4.7kB  
file = "./test_file.csv" 

try:
    os.open( file, os.O_RDONLY)
    df_data = pd.read_csv( file, index_col=0)

except: 
    df_data = pd.read_csv( url, index_col=0)
    df_data.to_csv( file)
```

Comment: You can pass `nrows=1` and then check the df.shape or length, so this will just read a single row

Comment: To check if a file exists , check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python , put a os.path.isfile check before downloading and reading into a df and in your except handle errors that are more related to the file having invalid characters which cause problem when loading into df.

Comment: `import os.path` then `os.path.isfile(fname)` will return True if the file exists

Comment: os.path.isfile( file) seems to be the best solution: to check before downloading a huge file:
if not os.path.isfile( file):

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `try` and catch `FileNotFoundError`:

```
url = "http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv" # 4.7kB  
file = "./test_file.csv" 

try:
    df_data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)

except FileNotFoundError: 
    df_data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
    df_data.to_csv(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists, and load from an url if it does not:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv"
f = "./test.csv"

if os.path.exists(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: A try catch would be recommended to teach the most pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

os.path.isfile( file) seems to me the best solution: checking before downloading a huge file:

```
if not os.path.isfile( file):
       urllib.urlretrieve(url, file)
df_data = pd.read_csv( file, index_col=0)
```

It's slower than uploading it directly in memory from url(dowload to disk and then upload into memory), but safer in my situation...
Thx to all